# Find the exact length of the curve.$ x=1+12t^2, y=2+8t^3, 0≤t≤1$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the exact length of the curve. $x=1+12t^2, y=2+8t^3, 0≤t≤1$

Comment: You probably know you need to set this up as an integral.  Not making an effort to show how, even if some difficulties are apparent, suggests you simply want Readers to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

For a parametric curve, its length is $L=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f'(t)]^2+[g'(t)]^2}dt$, where $f(t), g(t)$ are your two functions describing $x,y$ in terms of $t$, and you integrate $t$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

So calculate $f'(t), g'(t)$ to determine the integrand, and then integrate.

Can you take it from here?